# Lucee Upgrade Issues- Version 5.2.9 to 5.3.8

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

We are in the process of upgrading Lucee and running into a number of issues centered around Java and Java file dependencies based on what I am seeing in our log files. Right now, the work is being done on Windows 10 Development machine to work out the kinks, and then we will do the upgrade in Production. The Java version on the dev machine is: java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20. Any direction as to where to look to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

In our log files, we see that the jar is loading properly.

```
“INFO”,“ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-8”,“08/25/2021”,“15:07:39”,“OSGI”,“add bundle:C:\web\application.\lib\java\axis-1.4.0.L0001.jar”
```

Here is the error we are seeing:

```
“ERROR”,“ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-3”,“08/25/2021”,“15:08:31”,“OSGi”,"Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)] because it is exposed to package ‘javax.xml.namespace’ from resources stax.api [stax.api [37](R 37.0)] and org.lucee.xml.apis [org.lucee.xml.apis [12](R 12.0)] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)]
require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.jaxrpc)(bundle-version>=1.4.0))
|
provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.lucee.jaxrpc
stax.api [stax.api [37](R 37.0)]

Chain 2:
org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)]
require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j)(bundle-version>=1.5.1))
|
provide: [org.lucee.wsdl4j [199](R 199.0)] osgi.wiring.bundle; {bundle-version=1.5.1, osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j}
org.lucee.wsdl4j [org.lucee.wsdl4j [199](R 199.0)]
import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)
|
export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.xml.namespace
org.lucee.xml.apis [org.lucee.xml.apis [12](R 12.0)] Unresolved requirements: [[org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)] osgi.wiring.bundle; (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j)(bundle-version>=1.5.1))];Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)] because it is exposed to package ‘javax.xml.namespace’ from resources stax.api [stax.api [37](R 37.0)] and org.lucee.xml.apis [org.lucee.xml.apis [12](R 12.0)] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)]
require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.jaxrpc)(bundle-version>=1.4.0))
|
provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.lucee.jaxrpc
stax.api [stax.api [37](R 37.0)]

Chain 2:
org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)]
require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j)(bundle-version>=1.5.1))
|
provide: [org.lucee.wsdl4j [199](R 199.0)] osgi.wiring.bundle; {bundle-version=1.5.1, osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j}
org.lucee.wsdl4j [org.lucee.wsdl4j [199](R 199.0)]
import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)
|
export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.xml.namespace
org.lucee.xml.apis [org.lucee.xml.apis [12](R 12.0)] Unresolved requirements: [[org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)] osgi.wiring.bundle; (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j)(bundle-version>=1.5.1))];org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)] because it is exposed to package ‘javax.xml.namespace’ from resources stax.api [stax.api [37](R 37.0)] and org.lucee.xml.apis [org.lucee.xml.apis [12](R 12.0)] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)]
require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.jaxrpc)(bundle-version>=1.4.0))
|
provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.lucee.jaxrpc
stax.api [stax.api [37](R 37.0)]

Chain 2:
org.lucee.axis [org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)]
require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j)(bundle-version>=1.5.1))
|
provide: [org.lucee.wsdl4j [199](R 199.0)] osgi.wiring.bundle; {bundle-version=1.5.1, osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j}
org.lucee.wsdl4j [org.lucee.wsdl4j [199](R 199.0)]
import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)
|
export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.xml.namespace
org.lucee.xml.apis [org.lucee.xml.apis [12](R 12.0)] Unresolved requirements: [[org.lucee.axis [198](R 198.0)] osgi.wiring.bundle; (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.lucee.wsdl4j)(bundle-version>=1.5.1))]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)
at lucee.loader.osgi.BundleUtil.start(BundleUtil.java:112)
at lucee.loader.osgi.BundleUtil.start(BundleUtil.java:108)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil._start(OSGiUtil.java:1214)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil._startIfNecessary(OSGiUtil.java:1167)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil.loadBundleByPackage(OSGiUtil.java:453)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil.loadPackages(OSGiUtil.java:1244)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil._start(OSGiUtil.java:1211)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil._startIfNecessary(OSGiUtil.java:1167)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil.startIfNecessary(OSGiUtil.java:1162)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil._loadBundle(OSGiUtil.java:540)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil.loadBundles(OSGiUtil.java:1275)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil._start(OSGiUtil.java:1202)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil._startIfNecessary(OSGiUtil.java:1167)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil.startIfNecessary(OSGiUtil.java:1162)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil._loadBundle(OSGiUtil.java:540)
at lucee.runtime.osgi.OSGiUtil.loadBundle(OSGiUtil.java:492)
at lucee.commons.lang.ClassUtil.loadClassByBundle(ClassUtil.java:155)
at lucee.transformer.library.ClassDefinitionImpl.getClazz(ClassDefinitionImpl.java:110)
at lucee.runtime.config.ConfigWebImpl.getWSHandler(ConfigWebImpl.java:638)
at lucee.runtime.tag.Invoke.doWebService(Invoke.java:238)
at lucee.runtime.tag.Invoke.doEndTag(Invoke.java:190)
at secure.controllers.document.index_cfm$cf.call(/secure/controllers/document/index.cfm:334)
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1003)
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:926)
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:907)
at application_cfc$cf.udfCall(/Application.cfc:333)
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:650)
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1911)
at lucee.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener.call(ModernAppListener.java:437)
at lucee.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:216)
at lucee.runtime.listener.MixedAppListener.onRequest(MixedAppListener.java:44)
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2460)
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._execute(PageContextImpl.java:2450)
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.executeCFML(PageContextImpl.java:2421)
at lucee.runtime.engine.Request.exe(Request.java:45)
at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl._service(CFMLEngineImpl.java:1179)
at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:1125)
at lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineWrapper.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineWrapper.java:97)
at lucee.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:51)
```

Comment: You would probably be best asking on https://dev.lucee.org/, much more likely to find somewhere there who might know what this is.

Comment: ... also, this is from May, but I think it still applies, i.e. java 16 is not fully supported yet https://dev.lucee.org/t/java-16-isnt-supported-yet-before-anyone-asks/8353

Comment: Thanks. I already added to dev.lucee.org. Thanks for the link, I will have a look.